# I am trying to manipulate a specific link on a page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to isolate a link that is on my page and change the contents when the page is resized.

Below is the way I have selected the link but I may be way off haha!

HTML:

```
<a href="uniqueLinkInfo" class="roll-button button-slider">
    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Call Now!
</a>
```

JS:

```
var thisContent = $('a.roll-button[href="uniqueLinkInfo"]').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3;
});
```

I don't think this is the easiest way to do this.

My goal is to change "Call Now!" while leaving the "i" tag.

Then when the page goes back to mobile sizing I will use the same method to change it back.

Comment: As the content you're trying to change is within it's own text node then yep, that's the way you have to do it. You can make it a one-liner by wrapping the `Call Now!` text in another element, such as a `span`, though.

Comment: With a span, no JavaScript would be needed. Just a css rue based on width.

Comment: `document.querySelector('a.roll-button[href="uniqueLinkInfo"]').lastChild.data = "new value"` ...but putting the text in an element is definitely better, if that's an option for you.

Comment: or use two spans and toggle them with css and media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet it's easier to make a `<span>` and that's what they are for:

```js
$(function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('a.roll-button[href="uniqueLinkInfo"] span').text("Don't call me!");
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="uniqueLinkInfo" class="roll-button button-slider">
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <span class="text-content">Call Now!</span>
</a>
```

Also, there's another way without the use of JS, using CSS `@media` queries:

```css
.text-content-desktop {display: inline;}
.text-content-mobile {display: none;}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .text-content-desktop {display: none;}
  .text-content-mobile {display: inline;}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href="uniqueLinkInfo" class="roll-button button-slider">
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <span class="text-content-mobile">Call Now!</span> <span class="text-content-desktop">Don't Call Now!</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the **last** textNode and already have jQuery available, you can use a regexp for your replacement.

```js
var $link = $('a.roll-button[href="uniqueLinkInfo"]');
var newHtml = $link.html().replace(/([^>])+$/m, " Replaced!");
$link.html( newHtml );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="uniqueLinkInfo" class="roll-button button-slider">
    <i class="fa fa-phone">[phone icon]</i> Call Now!
</a>
```